# convert this code from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

When I convert this code from VB:

```
    Dim r As DialogResult = FldSource.ShowDialog()
        If r = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            lstPath.Items.Clear()
            lblSoLuong.Text = lstPath.Items.Count
            txtPath.Text = FldSource.SelectedPath
            Dim tenfile, FS() As FileInfo
            Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text)
            FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt")
            For Each tenfile In FS
                lstPath.Items.Add(tenfile.FullName)
            Next
            lblSoLuong.Text = lstPath.Items.Count
        End If
```

to C#:

```
try
            FolderBrowserDialog FldSource = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult r = FldSource.ShowDialog();
            if ( r == DialogResult.OK ) 
                lst_Path.Items.Clear();
                lbl_Soluong.Text = lst_Path.Items.Count.ToString();
                txt_Path.Text = FldSource.SelectedPath;
                FileInfo tenfile, FS();
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txt_Path.Text);
                FS= di.GetFiles(".txt");
```

I got error at this line:

```
 FS= di.GetFiles(".txt");
```

I wondered if Where my mistakes was???

Comment: Perhaps you can share with us the error you receive?

Comment: need a * in get files

Comment: Don't you missed the "*" in FS= di.GetFiles(".txt"); ?

Comment: you donot have * at the start of this line FS= di.GetFiles(".txt");

Comment: That's not the line giving you the error, it's the one before. This part `FS()` isn't valid.

Comment: Where's FS coming from??

Comment: `FileInfo tenfile, FS;` is valid.

Comment: @abhi yes, but FS is not an array then. So you won't be able to use `FS = di.GetFiles(<something>);`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Yes. There should not be any `()` after the FS.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the search pattern you use in VB:

```
FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt")
```

And in C#:

```
FS = di.GetFiles(".txt");
```

The change from VB to C# doesn't change how the methods are called, or the values passed to them.  You still need to send it the same search pattern.  (In fact, even in the VB version, it's *highly likely* that the implementation for `GetFiles()` was written in C# anyway.)

There's no difference in the inner workings, just in the syntax by which you invoke those inner workings.

Additionally, I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here:

```
FileInfo tenfile, FS();
```

If `FS` should be an array, you'd do this:

```
FileInfo tenfile;
FileInfo[] FS;
```

Though you can declare it even easier with implicit typing, not even needing the declaration statement:

```
var FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a variable this way in c#

```
FileInfo tenfile, FS();
```

If you need a FileInfo tenFile and an array of FileInfo FS, use

```
FileInfo tenfile;
FileInfo[] FS;
```

Comment: Try declaring `int x, y = 0;` The code will compile in .NET 4.0

Comment: @abhi, yes, but this is `FS()`, not `FS` . Which is not the same. And `Directory.GetFiles` returns a `FileInfo[]`, not a `FileInfo`.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Gotcha. he's using VB syntax to declare the array.

Comment: @abhi You get it ;) (and I got what you meant after a while...)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is create an array of `FileInfo`. In which case instead of this:

```
FileInfo tenfile, FS();
```

You need this:

```
FileInfo tenfile;
FileInfo[] FS;
```

Also, as others have pointed out, you are missing the `*` in your search string for `GetFiles`, but that won't give you an error, it'll just not do what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *

```
FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this:
    FS= di.GetFiles("*.txt");